# TextView setEllipsize to marquee causes nullpointerexception

Tags: android, textview, android-2.3-gingerbread

```
final TextView appTextView = new TextView(getContext());    
appTextView.setTextSize(12);
appTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
appTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
appTextView.setMaxLines(2);
appTextView.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
appTextView.setText("Some text");

addView(appTextView);

E/AndroidRuntime( 2448): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2448):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2448):    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:5317)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2448):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2448):    at com.venturezlab.tvlauncher.views.AppsLayout.refreshApps(AppsLayout.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2448):    at com.venturezlab.tvlauncher.views.AppsLayout.<init>(AppsLayout.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2448):    ... 25 more
```

Why? Without ellipsize this works fine.

Comment: Where is your code of initializing(`appTextView = findViewbyid(...)`) the `TextView`

Comment: What is your `addView(..)` contains?

Comment: It adds the textview to the linearlayout.

Comment: The error raising here only - `com.venturezlab.tvlauncher.views.AppsLayout.refreshApps(AppsLayout.java:51)`

Comment: It's only one step of the stacktrace, not the last

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17699/discussion-between-rankor-and-spk)

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am having trouble in my app in Android 4.4 with this same crash.